# Operations between one value and all other values of a different variable in R

Tags: r, loops

I need some help to solve the following issue.
I have a simplified dataset as this

```
from    to  class
red     1   A
blue    2   A
black   3   A
```

I would like to get the following result

```
from    to  class
red     1   A
blue    2   A
black   3   A
red     2   A
red     3   A
blue    1   A
blue    3   A
black   1   A
black   2   A
```

Basically, each value in "from" should be repeated n(class)-1 times. In this case, n(class) is 3, the sum of the classes having "A" as value, so 2 repetitions. Then, each new value in "from" needs to be associated with a value in "to" corresponding to all the other values in "to" but itself.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Are you just looking for `tidyr::complete(dd, from, to, class)`?

Comment: or `tidyr::expand(df, from, to, class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `complete()` function from tidyr to get all combinations of parameters from different columns. Please see [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html).

```
dt <- data.frame(from = c("red", "blue", "black"),
                 to = 1:3,
                 class = c("A", "A", "A"))

dt_complete <- tidyr::complete(dt, from, to, class)
```

I used all 3 columns here, but if you only want all combinations of "from" and "to", only use those.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
 unique(expand.grid(df1))
```